# 301 перенаправление

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

```
Redirect 301 /2021/ /st-2021/
```

Перенес страницу на другой адрес, как верно выполнить перенаправление так, чтобы позиции в выдаче сохранить?

Прописал правило в .htaccess, не работает, в чем дело?

Перенаправляет на страницу `site.ru/st-2021/?do=2021`

Необходимо на `site.ru/st-2021/`

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9-]+)/+$ index.php?do=em&po=$1&bl=true [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z-0-9-]+)/([a-z-0-9-]+)/+$ index.php?do=$1&po=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z-0-9-]+)/+$ index.php?do=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: С какого адреса перенаправляет, с `site.ru/2021/` или с `site.ru/2021/?do=2021`?

Comment: C /2021/ на /st-2021/, а попадаю на /st-2021/?do=2021. В .htaccess еще есть правила возможно из-за них?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй

```
Redirect 301 /2021/ /st-2021/
```

или используй PHP

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: http://site.ru/st-2021/"); 
exit();
?>
```

Еще интересный вариант - плагин Redirection  или Safe Redirect Manager (если сайт работает на вордпресс).

Comment: Почему через Redirect в конец строчки добавляется ?do=2021?

Comment: Вероятно, это связано с другим правилом в .htaccess или скриптом, который используется на сайте.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос правила из системного файла, быть может из-за них что не так?